# Swift: NSData(contentsOfURL) crashing on XCode 6.1

Tags: swift, xcode6.1

Before upgrading to XCode6.1 I was using the method NSData.dataWithContents() and it was working perfectly all the images were downloading. Today I have updated to XCode 6.1 and it forces me to use the function like this:

```
NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: completeUrl)!)!
```

and when I run the application it crashes on it with message:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I have tried many things but nothing works. I am looking for any simple alternative for this to download images from a given URL.

Answer (score 7):

Since the initalization of `NSURL` may fail due to several reasons you should better use it this way:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: completeUrl) {
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) { // may return nil, too
        // do something with data
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I have done it with a better way then this.

Answer (score 1):

More better way to download files is:

```
let request:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: completeUrl)!)
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: { (response:NSURLResponse!, imageData:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
     var filePath:String = pathString + "/" + fileName
     imageData.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)
})
```

It is working very nicely and also it gives you more control on the request.

Comment: Note that `NSURL(..)!` may crash your app if the URL fails.

Comment: If you're looking for best (easy to extend and with 'control' on request) way to downloading files in your app, you should consider using NSOperation. Nice example in Swift is here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift